# Aurelia Typescript skeleton -navigation error with npm start command

Tags: aurelia

I'm using Node 6.3 and npm 3.10.3
I'm successfully able to run the command of `npm install` but when i execute `npm start` I get the following error
I'm referring to this github repo https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-webpack

Error is

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "server:dev"
>   npm ERR! node v6.3.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.0-beta.3.0.1
>   server:dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node
>   ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --inline
>   --progress --profile --watch` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.0-beta.3.0.1
>   server:dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node
>   ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --inline
>   --progress --profile --watch'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most
>   likely a problem with the aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails
>   on your system: npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node
>   ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --inline
>   --progress --profile --watch npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs
>   aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack npm ERR! Or if that isn't
>   available, you can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls
>   aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     D:\Afzal.Qureshi\My
>   Projects\AureliaTs\skeleton-navigation-master\skeleton-typescript-webpack\npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start" npm ERR!
>   node v6.3.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.0-beta.3.0.1 start: `npm run
>   server:dev` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack@1.0.0-beta.3.0.1 start script 'npm
>   run server:dev'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of
>   node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a
>   problem with the aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack package, npm ERR!
>   not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your
>   system: npm ERR!     npm run server:dev npm ERR! You can get
>   information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!
>   npm bugs aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack npm ERR! Or if that isn't
>   available, you can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls
>   aurelia-skeleton-navigation-webpack npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     D:\My
>   Projects\AureliaTs\skeleton-navigation-master\skeleton-typescript-webpack\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're using the nightly version of the skeleton. Be sure to pull a release version.

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/1.0.0-beta.3.0.1/skeleton-typescript-webpack